# Glitch with tween engine and libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having a barely noticeable but annoying and random glitch tweening an actor with tween engine. The actor is just a group with an image. The tween is just a linear from the right of the screen to the left and repeating.

FPS is always showing 60.

Any idea?

This is the code:

```
public class BackgroundScreen extends AbstractScreen {

public BackgroundScreen() {     
  stage = new Stage();
  stage.setViewport(Properties.VIRTUAL_WIDTH, Properties.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, false);
  createRock(); 
}

private void createRock() {
   rock = new GameElement(atlas.createSprite("obj-stone"));
   rock.setX(Properties.VIRTUAL_WIDTH);
   rock.setY(100);
   float duration=5f;
   Tween.to(rock, ActorAccessor.POSITION_XY, duration/2).ease(Linear.INOUT).target(-rock.getWidth(), rock.getY()).repeat(Tween.INFINITY, 0).start(Resources.tweenManager);
   stage.addActor(rock);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  Resources.tweenManager.update(delta);
  stage.act(delta);
  stage.draw();
}

}
```

**UPDATE**

This is the link to a youtube video with the effect. Two considerations:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pVJbGFciyo

a) When screenrecording the video, the glich is more pronounced as you can watch.
b) I can't see any glitch on my Galaxy Nexus. 
c) I did the same tween with just libgdx actions and the glitch is the same
d) Somehow it is related to my PC.

Comment: You'll have to describe "random glitch" in more detail.  Its not clear what problem you're seeing.

Comment: I will upload a video asap.

Comment: if you are trying to do a simple tween on a stage, have you considered using actions instead? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#wiki-actions

Comment: I watched the video, still have no idea what the problem is. Describe the problem. Stop saying "Glitch", it is not descriptive of a particular problem.

Comment: I stopped developing that game, sorry. Anyway, I uploaded the video to showcase the "glitch" as I knew it's something difficult to describe just in words.

Comment: I think you are referring to the tearing of the sprite as it moves... this just means you don't have vsync enabled. Basically the screen is displaying partial updates. If you mean something else then you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You should play with the tween equation.
Off the bet i'd say that `Linear.INOUT` is what causing the sprite to glitch. maybye simply try running it with `Linear.IN` will do the trick.